# separate sphinx build and source directories for version control

Tags: python-sphinx

I have a working directory containing my project and it is in a version control system. I'd like to create a `doc` directory inside my project that contains *only* restructured text files for `sphinx`.

That is, I don't want `sphinx` to build html files inside my project, but put them outside so they don't get put into version control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So if you question is 'How can I build documentation outside of the source tree', the [documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/quickstart.html#running-the-build) helps:

```
sphinx-build -b html sourcedir builddir
```

Just point builddir to a location outside of your source tree.

Or, depending on your version control system, add the directory you generate your documentation to an 'ignore file' (e.g. `.gitignore`, `.hgignore`, ...)

Comment: I was trying it with sphinx-quickstart--the doc does help, thanks for pointing me to the right place.

Comment: For me, this approach still looks for index.rst in the source code folder... I've tried to specify `master_doc` option in my custom `config.py` but it does not work.